# Is Elasticsearch optimized for inserts?

Tags: elasticsearch, insert

I develop for a relatively large online store with a PHP backend, and it uses elasticsearch for some things (like text search, logging... etc).

Now, I'd like to start storing all kinds of information about user activity in ES. For instance, every page view (for instance: user enter product page/category page ,etc).

Is ES optimized for such a heavy load of continuous inserts, or should I consider some alternatives, like for instance having some sort of a buffer layer where I store all of my immediate inserts in memory, and then every minute or so, insert them into ES in bulk?

What is the industry standard? Or am I worrying in vain and ES is optimized for that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch, when properly sized to handle your load, is definitely a valid alternative for such a use case.

You might decide, however, to store that streaming data into another cluster which is different from your production cluster, so as to not impact the health of the production cluster too much.

There are a lot variables to arrive at the correct decision, and we don't have enough information here, but it's definitely a valid way.